# what Data Structure do we usually to use in hash table storing hash key?

Tags: hashtable

What is the data structure storing hash key? Is it a linked list?

Comment: Based on this question, I can only say no, you don't "know hash table."

Comment: okay Matt :) please enlighten me

Comment: A question mark coupled with a sentence would be nice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the language. Take a look at this question:

[How would you implement a hashtable in language x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282/how-would-you-implement-a-hashtable-in-language-x)

which suggests you could store the hash key as a `char*` in C.