# Hash table in C

Tags: c, algorithm, hashtable

How to implement a hashtable in C without use of libraries? I have seen many answers where they've implemented Hashtables in C using some libraries. I want to know the actual concept behind it and how to write a raw implementation of a Hash Map in C.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282/how-would-you-implement-a-hashtable-in-language-x

Answer (score 2):

Then the best thing might be, getting an book on algorithms (like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms ) read the wikipedia article and especially the references ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table ) and try to implement this with the "raw" language.

Also if you google for lecture slides you find many algorithmic explanations how hashing can be done with few operations (just with use of arrays and simple arithmetic).

You might also want to test your implementation with some forced collisions to get a feeling for this.

And finally a warning: Don't use your hashing algorithm in production, there are reasons, why there are libraries for that!